# Adonis JS v5 relationship missing model attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, adonis.js, lucid

I am learning how to use the [Adonis framework](https://adonisjs.com/) **(v5)** and as the tradition dictates it, I am creating a todo list api to test it out.

The problem I am having is regarding the relationship between the `User` and `Todo` entities.

Here are the two models:

```js
// file: app/Models/Todo.ts

export default class Todo extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @belongsTo(() => User, {
    foreignKey: 'id',
  })
  public author: BelongsTo<typeof User>

  @column()
  public completed: boolean

  @column()
  public title: string

  @column()
  public description: string | null

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt: DateTime
}
```

```js
// file: app/Models/User.ts

export default class User extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @column()
  public username: string

  @column({ serializeAs: null })
  public password: string

  @hasMany(() => Todo, {
    foreignKey: 'author',
  })
  public todos: HasMany<typeof Todo>

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt: DateTime

  @beforeSave()
  public static async hashPassword(user: User) {
    if (user.$dirty.password) {
      // Only hash password if required
      user.password = await Hash.make(user.password)
    }
  }
}
```

I did not include the migrations files but I will edit this question if they are needed.

What I am expecting is that I should be able to create and save Users into my database, the same for Todo entries and link the todo entries to their author. [The documentation provides us with an example](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/relationships#has-many) but I don't see where I am doing something wrong.

So to test it out I am using the `node ace repl` command as follow:

```
// log of running the commands in the AdonisJS v5 REPL
> loadModels()
recursively reading models from "app/Models"
Loaded models module. You can access it using the "models" variable
> undefined
> const testUser = await models.User.create({ username: 'testUser', password: 'password' })
undefined
> await testUser.related('todos').create({ title: 'Example todo entry' })
Uncaught:
Exception: E_MISSING_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE: "User.todos" expects "author" to exist on "Todo" model, but is missing
    at <my-app-directory>\REPL23:1:39
    at Proxy.related (<my-app-directory>\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\src\Orm\BaseModel\index.js:1436:18)
    at HasMany.boot (<my-app-directory>\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\src\Orm\Relations\HasMany\index.js:74:12)
    at KeysExtractor.extract (<my-app-directory>\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\src\Orm\Relations\KeysExtractor.js:28:39)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at <my-app-directory>\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\src\Orm\Relations\KeysExtractor.js:32:23
>
```

I don't understand the error message since `author` actually exists on the `Todo` model.

How can I solve this problem and get my todo app up and running?

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is that you are missing a field inside your model.

You need to define all fields with the `@column()` decorator. In your example, you are not defining the column `author`.

When creating a relation, you must have one column (the FK) and one relation.

If we assume that you have a column `user_id` inside your `todos` table, then you need to add the column `user_id` inside your `Todo` model.

Here is a correct example:

```
class User extends BaseModel {
  // ...
  @hasMany(() => Todo)
  todos: HasMany<typeof Todo>
}

class Todo extends BaseModel {
  @column()
  user_id: number

  @belongsTo(() => User)
  author: BelongsTo<typeof User>
}
```